# Loop through all files in a directory and upload to s3

Tags: files, aws

How do you apply a command to all files in a directory, such as `aws s3 cp [name] s3://[bucketname]` where `[name]` is the name of each file in the directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass all files in directory as one argument to perl script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187582/pass-all-files-in-directory-as-one-argument-to-perl-script)

Comment: No, because it requires using a perl script?

Comment: Also, please explain the downvote.

Comment: it does not require a perl script. The fact that the program is written in perl doesn't matter to the question or its answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest referring to the [official documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

> **Recursively copying local files to S3**
>
> When passed with the parameter `--recursive`, the following `cp` command recursively copies all files under a specified directory to a specified bucket and prefix while excluding some files by using an `--exclude` parameter. In this example, the directory myDir has the files test1.txt and test2.jpg:
>
> `aws s3 cp myDir s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude "*.jpg"`
>
> Output:
>
> `upload: myDir/test1.txt to s3://mybucket/test1.txt`

Maybe use `--dryrun` at first if you are unsure about the effects.

Comment: wow the cli contains a lot! was wondering though also if linux has a way to pass it to a filename to general command

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you seem to be thinking of wildcards. However it always depends on the very command if and how it treats multiple arguments. The (unix) `cp` for example will copy file A to file B with `cp A B` but copy files A, B, and C into directory D with `cp A B C D`. The `s3` documentation does not state examples with more than two arguments: source and destination, but will treat multiple files with `--recursive`. For a file-per-file approach, check @romeo-ninov 's approach (`for`-loop) or try to use `parallel` for speeding up by parallely executing one command per file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try something like:

```
aws s3 cp /path/* s3://[bucketname]
```

if you insist to make it in loop you can try this for example:

```
for i in /path/*
do
aws s3 cp "$i" s3://[bucketname]
done
```

Comment: Can this loop work directly in the command line, or would it require piping to an external script? Also, is there a way to dry run this just in case things blow up?

Comment: @ina, what do you want to pipe to external script?

Comment: it was suggested above that this was a duplicate for pipe to perl - i'm trying to do this without needing to pipe to external